# Plot fast changing data using OOP approach

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot the results from each iteration of an algorithm (data points are obtained quite fast). I´ve already looked at `matplotlib.animation` and a bunch of solutions using other packages but none of them uses an OOP approach.

I came up with this code:

```
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import random


class LivePlot:

    def __init__(self, title, x_label, y_label):
        self.x = []
        self.y = []

        self.fig = plt.figure()
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

        # Create a blank line (will be updated in animate)
        self.line, = self.ax.plot([], [])

        # Add labels
        plt.xlabel(x_label)
        plt.ylabel(y_label)
        plt.title(title)

        self.anim = animation.FuncAnimation(self.fig, self.animate,
                                            init_func=self.__init,
                                            blit=True)

    def __init(self):
        self.line.set_data([], [])
        return self.line,

    def animate(self, i):

        # Update line with new Y values
        self.line.set_data(self.x, self.y)

        return self.line,

    # Set up plot to call animate() function periodically
    def plot(self, xs, ys):
        self.x.append(xs)
        self.y.append(ys)
        plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pl = LivePlot(title='test', x_label='iter', y_label='score')
    for x in range(100):
        y = random.randint(1,4)
        pl.plot(x, y)
```

It doesn´t work, the plot window disappear almost immediately without plotting any data.

Comment: A FuncAnimation is meant to be created once, not 100 times. But after creation it needs to stay in memory.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I edited the code after some reading and following your correction. Still not working

Comment: Now the animation is running , but your x and y arrays only contain one point. If you close the window, they will contain the next point but no new window is shown. Mind that `plt.show()` should be called exactly once, not 100 times.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I placed the `plt.show()` at the end of the `__init__` function but as expected the execution is blocked. I added `plt.ion()` and even set `block=False` but still nothing.

Comment: Yeah, because your x and y still only contain a single point.